# Regex exact length of whole string

Tags: regex

I want to match a string of exact 3 length. I am using the following regex

```
("\\d?[A-Za-z]{2,3}\d?")
```

Here the string can have 1 digit either at start or at end of the string, or the string can have 3 letters.Is there any way to define length of the matching string like :

```
("(\\d?[A-Za-z]{2,3}\d?){3}") // it does not work
```

I have another solution of it.

```
("(\\d[A-Za-z]{2})|([A-Za-z]{2}\\d)|([A-Za-z]{3})")
```

But I just want to know if there is any way to define length of whole matching string.

Comment: I am not using any regex tool. I am writing a java program in eclipse, Where I am using regex.

Comment: Can you use a lookahead?  `(?=^.{3}$)\d?[A-Za-z]{2,3}\d?`  Your regex also looks like it might collapse to `[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]`.

Comment: I can not use lookahead. But collapsed regex working fine.

Answer (score 6):

```
^.{3}$
```

If this isn't really your answer you need to specify it better. You have zero solutions not several. What exactly are you trying to match. Give a couple examples.

http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

```
^(\d[a-zA-Z]{2}|[a-zA-Z]{2}\d|[a-zA-Z]{3})$
```

If you want that letters and numbers thing.

If you want the extra stuff at the end to be possible without the string being over you can just look for the space afterwards.

> ^(\d[a-zA-Z]{2}|[a-zA-Z]{2}\d|[a-zA-Z]{3})\s

From the comments:

So it's

```
^[^\s]{3}\s\d{7}\s.\d{6}
```

? -- '^' start of line, '[^\s]' not a space. '{3}' three of those. '\s' a space. '\d' a digit. '{7}' seven of those. '\s' a space. '.' some character. '\d' a digit. '{6}' of those.

Regex is basically just programmatically a way of describing what you're looking for. If you can properly form the question of what you want to match it's easy to write that directly in regex.

Comment: No, it is not working. I am giving you few examples, actually what I want to match is something like this -  'WDC 1234567L123456'  or '4YL 1001101L110100' or 'GH4 1234567L123456'. Previously I used following regex - ((\\d?[A-Za-z]{2,3}\\d?)\\s\\d{7}[A-Z]{1}\\d{6}) but this regex was also matching a string something like 'ZN 1234567L123456' so I decided to define length of string before space but I did not get any solution so finally I have used ((\\d[A-Za-z]{2})|([A-Za-z]{2}\\d)|([A-Za-z]{3}))\\s\\d{7}[A-Z]{1}\\d{6}. It is working fine but I do not want to specify all conditions but length.

Comment: @DineshChoudhary You should update your original question with those examples. As such, what they are and which part you'd like to match. Way more helpful than describing what you think you want to match.

Comment: Only important question seems to be how do you know when the section you want to match is over? After you have those three characters, then what happens? Is it a space? Three non-space characters followed by a space?

Comment: Yes there are three non-space characters followed by a space. I simply find out that section by this regex, there are three non space characters then there is a space then seven digits after that One character and then 6 digits.

Comment: So it's ^[^\s]{3}\s\d{7}\s.\d{6} ? -- '^' start of line, '[^\s]' not a space. '{3}' three of those. '\s' a space. '\d' a digit. '{7}' seven of those. '\s' a space. '.' some character. '\d' a digit. '{6}' of those.

Answer (score 2):

Your three solutions will match also longer strings. I suggest you to use word boundary (`\b`) or line boundary (`^` and `$`):

```
\b([a-zA-Z]{2}\d|\d[a-zA-Z]{2}|[a-zA-Z]{3})\b
```

or

```
^([a-zA-Z]{2}\d|\d[a-zA-Z]{2}|[a-zA-Z]{3})$
```

based on the specific usage.

EDIT: fixed the regex, matching also 3 digits.

Comment: Yes, You are right but can we use first solution ("\\d?[A-Za-z]{2,3}\d?") and define length of it? because I do not want to use this solution because in it we have to define all the conditions, here we have length 3 but what if the length is longer.

Comment: Uhm, I fear that in that way you will match also strings with length from 2 to 5, I can't see how to fix that.

Comment: So, the solution you have provided is best according to you?

Comment: As far as I know yes, but I'm quite new in regex. You can wait a bit and see if someone else have smarter ways to solve your problem ;)